# What is the best way for show a table on mobile app?

Tags: tables, ios, lists, card-views

I was asked to create a mobile application to display datas.

Problem is that the person who created the wireframes was clearly thinking on a website rather than a mobile app. Many people use cardview or listview these days.

I'm trying to come up with a better solution to display that information. However I'm having trouble figure that out.

[image: Credit Detail]

Some tables can be 48 lines.

Which way is the best solution for showing this table on mobile application?

Comment: What part of the data table is important?

Comment: is Expandable  card view a good solution?

Comment: Installment number Maturity date Loan Amount  Remaining amount Installment amount and Payment Amount are importent colums. I know its too much :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be forced to allow horizontal scrolling since all the tables don't fit the layout width. However, the ability to lock a column so that it is fixed to the left of the screen while the other columns can be scrolled around will simplify the process since I can see that a few fields are interlinked.

Furthermore, if it is a requirement to show all the table headings without introducing the need to scroll, you can have a state where all the headings are compressed before an interaction (ex: scroll or tap) expands them.

Finally, you may even want to add a prompt asking the user to rotate their phone into landscape mode, allowing for more horizontal real estate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the horizontal scroll for this. Is your table a simple/complex table? In addition to this is there any comparison of data? Hope this solves the problem.

For reference: Check it in responsive mode

http://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables

https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

http://trydevkit.com/blog-post/responsive-tables-best-practices-and-examples/ee7961a6-a22e-610b-70d0-533c85cc59b6